# What is the difference between @SpringBootConfiguration vs @Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What is the difference between `@SpringBootConfiguration` and `@Configuration`? I cannot find much details on it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per Springboot docs (hierarchy below), `@Configuration` is a part of `@SpringBootConfiguration` which ultimately has `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
-------> @SpringBootConfiguration
       -------> @Configuration
```

---

*@SpringBootApplication*

```
Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
        @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
        @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM,
                classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class) })
public @interface SpringBootApplication {
...}
```

*@SpringBootConfiguration*

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Configuration
public @interface SpringBootConfiguration {

}
```

*@Configuration*

```
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @Component
    public @interface Configuration {
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**SpringBootConfiguration**

> Indicates that a class provides Spring Boot application **@Configuration**. Can be used as an alternative to the Spring's standard **@Configuration** annotation so that configuration can be found automatically (for example in tests).
>   Application should only ever include one **@SpringBootConfiguration** and most idiomatic Spring Boot applications will inherit it from **@SpringBootApplication**.

**Source**

[Documentation on SpringBootConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html)

Answer (score 3):

> As per the Spring documentation, `@SpringBootConfiguration` is just an
>   alternative to the Spring standard `@Configuration` annotation. The only
>   difference between the two is that the `@SpringBootConfiguration` allows
>   the configuration to be found automatically.
>
> This is specifically useful when writing tests.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2019/09/springbootconfiguration-annotation-spring-boot.html

Comment: Hi, I have trouble understanding the statement. "The only difference between the two is that the @SpringBootConfiguration allows the configuration to be found automatically." can you please give me an example?